# Verifone MX915 - Tampered Device

Tags: verifone

Does anyone know how to fix the tampering condition on Verifone MX915?
My log file prompted "RTC frequency too low".
Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Additional information, RTC stands for real time clock. I assume there must something wrong with the internal battery. All suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are using your device for but I would suggest simply sending it for repair. It does seem like this is a hardware issue that caused tamper and you might not be able to revive the device to the state it had before the tamper as most of the cryptographic material is wiped when it is detected.